# Is there a library, module, or model that I can use to get the pronunciation/phonetics of words in Python?

Tags: python

I want to figure out the pronunciations of the words without using an API. Also, I tried using the big phony module used in this link: https://github.com/repp/big-phoney. However, when I tried implementing it, it gives me this error: Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL). And I don't know how to solve this error and get the pronunciation as the output.

This is the code I implemented based on the link:

```
from big_phoney import BigPhoney

phoney = BigPhoney()

print(phoney.phonize('pterodactyl'))
```

But it just gives me the error mentioned above. How do I solve this error or is there another way to get the pronunciation of words in Python?

Comment: pyttsx3 should help.

Comment: Use Pyttsx3 or Check out the libraries by https://pypi.org/user/aparrish/